# What should be considered when selecting a windowing function when smoothing a time series?

Tags: time-series

If one wants to smooth a time series using a window function such as Hanning, Hamming, Blackman etc. what are the considerations for favouring any one window over another?

Comment: Now that dsp.SE has opened, I wonder if you might have better luck asking this over there?  Maybe cross-post and see what happens, since they aren't getting that much traffic yet anyhow.

Comment: @sheegaon - thanks for the heads up about dsp.SE. I have now posted this question there too.

Comment: If you get an answer over there please add it here, or a link to it, as an answer.

Comment: Looks like this got plenty of attention at [dsp.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/208/169). @Louis, you should probably post the answer and assign yourself the bounty if babelproofreader doesn't come back in time.

Comment: This post has been answered at dsp.SE [here][1].


  [1]: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-should-be-considered-when-selecting-a-windowing-function-when-smoothing-a-ti

Comment: This question has been answered at dsp.SE [here][1].


  [1]: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-should-be-considered-when-selecting-a-windowing-function-when-smoothing-a-ti

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I tried to post the link to the answer at dsp.SE as an answer, as per Tal Fishman's comment, but the forum software automatically converted this to a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been answered at dsp.SE: [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/208/what-should-be-considered-when-selecting-a-windowing-function-when-smoothing-a-ti).

(P.S.: I don't know why the forum software converted babelproofreader's answer into a comment?!? Now it seems to have worked...)